# Use string literal array as type

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I want to use a single array `const fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']` as a normal array, and as a `type`.

I should be able to do this:
`const x: fruits // => only accepts 'banana', 'apple' or 'orange'`

And also be able to do this:
`@IsIn(fruits)`

---

I've tried to declare the array as `<const>`, such as:

```js
const fruits = <const>['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
type Fruits = typeof fruits[number] // this evaluates to type: "banana" | "apple" | "orange"
```

But `@IsIn(fruits)` will return the following error:

```
Argument of type 'readonly ["banana", "apple", "orange"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
  The type 'readonly ["banana", "apple", "orange"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'any[]'.ts(2345)
```

So I thought if I created two arrays, a normal one and a readonly one, it should work. So I tried this:

```js
const fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
const fruits_readonly: <const>[...fruits]
type Fruits = typeof fruits_readonly[number]
```

But now `Fruits` evalutes to `type: string` instead of `type: "banana" | "apple" | "orange"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) produce objects and arrays with `readonly` elements.  If you want to get the string-literal and tuple type benefits that the `const` assertion buys you while also un-`readonly`-ing the result, you could write a helper function to do that.  I'll call it `mutable()`:

```
const mutable = <T>(t: T): { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] } => t

const fruits = mutable(['banana', 'apple', 'orange'] as const);
// const fruits: ["banana", "apple", "orange"]
```

That will work one level deep.  If you have nested object/array types you might want to make a `DeepMutable` type and `deepMutable()` helper function:

```
type DeepMutable<T> =
    T extends object ? { -readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepMutable<T[K]> } : T

const deepMutable = <T>(t: T) => t as DeepMutable<T>;
```

That works the same for the above case,

```
const alsoFruits = deepMutable(['banana', 'apple', 'orange'] as const);
// const alsoFruits: ["banana", "apple", "orange"]
```

but the distinction becomes important with nested objects:

```
const readonlyDeepFruits = {
    yellow: ["banana", "lemon"],
    red: ["cherry", "apple"],
    orange: ["orange", "mango"],
    green: ["lime", "watermelon"]
} as const;
/* const readonlyDeepFruits: {
    readonly yellow: readonly ["banana", "lemon"];
    readonly red: readonly ["cherry", "apple"];
    readonly orange: readonly ["orange", "mango"];
    readonly green: readonly ["lime", "watermelon"];
} */

const partiallyMutableDeepFruits = mutable(readonlyDeepFruits);
/* const partiallyMutableDeepFruits: {
    yellow: readonly ["banana", "lemon"];
    red: readonly ["cherry", "apple"];
    orange: readonly ["orange", "mango"];
    green: readonly ["lime", "watermelon"];
} */

const fullyMutableDeepFruits = deepMutable(readonlyDeepFruits);
/* const fullyMutableDeepFruits: {
    yellow: ["banana", "lemon"];
    red: ["cherry", "apple"];
    orange: ["orange", "mango"];
    green: ["lime", "watermelon"];
} */
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgVygQwEYBsCmMC8MA8AKgHwAUUAXDIQJRUDeMAtAE6bIAm46AnjANoBpGAEswMANaYeIAGbUAulUJCFMAL65iMKAFgAUAdCRYslghFQIueEjRZS-AOSpkYN8icAaGE+QAHfyxvXxAWNwBzTCc1ZGtjaBoAbgMAelSYBNNzSwgqfgAiV3d3Ap8CgKDMMpgCsMjqhQMDKB5-bAARTEx-AFk7DEwibRwDGHHqGEwADyhMMA5rEFQAK0xgWAB+GEZWdi4wXgFhMUlpOUUqLp7+lEGiVW1NZWb9LJgObr6BrBth8mUNC0OhgcRg12+dywwxShje4GgoPQEBAADEclYbJ8bj9MI4XB53CE-IFgj4nPUwFEYqD4gioMk0hl3shkWiMXkBEVCcgahVSdVypSogUmnD3mxONweBD0RZMXh6GMJjxMOh0CAAO75bklXnlLBwcCirzK8ZsDg64AAC0wLBYPD5lSwJrNMGFmB1Hr5cEiIFd+gmMAibHmOvQIjggtqmuQcxYUY1YFFBk0YKysNSACpMvSYJKDrxZRyGG6C9KYKr1VqqOXDnxCsUPHzDcaFLCg3Wjhba-sK4UbXaHU6BaKOxMu3wPb2pfWud7yr6qf722W+3OQ90wDPCw2ChGo3zY-HE23YZos6lXu9-MgWFARKzeLd7Jhi-LrHhEFC8ZP37lGX0bNcxMGBb3vR91R4F9Bn-KxS0DFU1Q1bV83XI5Gx5FtMCNZNV0Q81MEtNDZwwgpB3tR1ymdRpx3GacSN3edwipaMCiXCIVzo4NQ23Rj+33SM2OPO1Tzw88YEva881kBAoJgrA4M-D4vgU390JlL45QAzMc3eWT5NxJSEKDKsUJ1JtSgNHCzzXYiB1tSiRyqMc3QYwoF1qDiuLdTcwy5A9hLjUS1Vs-QLyvfQgA)

Comment: Thanks, this works :) But I still don't understand why `typeof fruits_readonly[number]` doesn't evaluate to `type: "banana" | "apple" | "orange"`. Would you explain to me, please?

Comment: Oh, sorry... in `const fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']`, `fruits` is inferred as type `string[]`, so the compiler has already forgotten the identity of the particular strings passed into it.  So `[...fruits]` will also be `string[]`.  If you want the compiler to remember `"banana" | "apple" | "orange"` you need to tell it not to throw away information while it still has it... that's what `as const` does (among other things).